# how to find element in html using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, file-get-contents

I am trying to find an element in html document using php.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
            $handle = fopen("exercise/Exercise.php", "r");
            $file = fread($handle ,8192);
            $handle = file_get_html('exercise/Exercise.php');
            if (!empty($handle)) {
              $ret = $handle->find('div[id=abc]');
             }
```

but I have no idea What to do with `$ret` now? or even check has it found `<div id="abc">` or not?is this even the right way I don't know because I am not very good at php?

Edit that question is way to vast for me understand.

Comment: echo `$ret` and find out

Comment: @Ghost Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\csstutorial.php on line 19
Array

Comment: @PaulCrovella ` How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP? ` it is far to vast could you point to it where should start looking?

Comment: its supposed to be `$handle->find('div[id=abc]', 0);` point to it directly, its an ID anyway and supposed to be unique

Comment: Are you trying to do a live search? or just the data from a file?

Comment: @Adsy2010 data from the file. `"exercise/Exercise.php"`

Comment: @Ghost now don't laugh or be angry but how do you do that?

Comment: use file_get_contents if its actually in the file itself, then search for the phrase your after

Comment: @Adsy2010 then it gives this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on string in C:\xampp\htdocs\csstutorial.php on line 18`

Comment: @qtpseleniumSupport the `fopen` is uneeded in this case, just use `file_get_html` that does the opening already and loads it into SimpleHTMLDom object. from the parent object, use `->find` method and point to your desired element, you could also use basic css selectors, it would work `div#abc` or something, and yes you should point to index zero `0` since you're looking for an element which has an id of that, and elements assigned with an ID is usually unique.

Comment: @Ghost I have another question after finding the element `<div>` is their a function available by which I can delete the entire div `<div> //some text </div>`

Comment: you can check out the simple-html-dom manual for details, i haven't answered this tag question for a while now, their API is very easy to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its supposed to be

```
 $handle->find('div[id=abc]', 0);
```